# Labeling values in ggplot outside geom_smooth threshold

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to label values in ggplot only if they are outside the interval of confidence (geom_smooth area). Below is my example where I can label all of them.

```
a <- sample(1:15)
b <- sample(-6:-20)
c <-sample(letters,15)
x1 <- data.frame(a, b, c)

gg <- ggplot(x1, aes(x = a, y = b)) + labs(x = "New x label", y= "New x label") + 
  geom_point()+ geom_smooth(method=lm) + geom_text(aes(label=c),hjust=2, vjust=1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make the fit prior to the `ggplot` call and create a variable with labels for points outside the confidence region.

```
## Get fit, and make a variable with labels for points outside conf. interval
fit <- lm(b ~ a)
dat <- predict(fit, interval="confidence")
x1$inside <- ifelse(x1$b < dat[,"upr"] & x1$b > dat[,"lwr"], "", as.character(x1$c))

gg <- ggplot(x1, aes(x = a, y = b)) +
  labs(x = "New x label", y= "New x label") + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method=lm) + geom_text(aes(label=inside),hjust=2, vjust=1)
gg
```

[image]

Another option would be using `ggplot_build` to extract the data from `ggplot` and use that to determine which points should be labeled.

```
## Use this to get data about the curve
info <- ggplot_build(gg)[[1]][[2]]
```